# How to perform validations with ngClass in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a form in which i applied ngclass to show error when form value is not given, unfortunately it shows error when the form gets loaded for the first time.

So by default when the form is loaded my input tag is in-valid, so it is showing error, i am not sure what to do.

Can someone help me pls.

My html,

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" class="nobottommargin adminloginform" novalidate>
    <label class="col-sm-4 text-right norightpadding">First Name</label>
      <div class="input-group" [ngClass]="{errmsg: !form.controls['lastname'].valid }" >
        <input type="text" [formControl]="form.controls['lastname']" >
      </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
              <button type="submit" >Register now</button>
            </div>
```

My ts,

```
export class SignUp {

constructor(public fbld: FormBuilder, http: Http, public config: Config, public router: Router) {
    this.http = http;
    this.form = fbld.group({
        firstname: ['', Validators.required],
    });
    this.header = this.config.header1;
}

onSubmit(form: ISignup): any {

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    this.http.post(this.header + 'signup', form, { headers: headers })
        .subscribe(
        response => {
            if (response.json().error_code == 0) {
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            }
            else {
                console.log(response.json().message);
            }
        });
}
```

my css,

```
    .errmsg{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add **`pristine`** as shown,

```
[ngClass]="{errmsg: (!form.controls['lastname'].valid &&
                     !form.controls['lastname'].pristine)}"
```

***Show validation only when form is submitted*** for this please check below plunker.

https://plnkr.co/edit/mJFftirG3ATDpnJRWmKN?p=preview

Comment: That worked .....but i want validations only  when the form is submiited and i tried this but not wrkng

Comment: [ngClass]="{errmsg: !form.controls['lastname'].valid &&
                      || (!form.controls['lastname'].pristine && form.submitted)

Comment: You just need to declare one variable named submitted with default false value and when button is clicked just change it to true.  And change form.submitted to submitted only. It will work.

Comment: Please come up with separate question so others can also help. And few questions alredy exist for the same.

Comment: Micronycs,can you see it,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146587/how-to-show-validation-on-button-click-in-typescript

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/mJFftirG3ATDpnJRWmKN?p=preview check I posted answer to your question which shows how to show validation on btn submit.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" class="nobottommargin adminloginform" novalidate>
    <label class="col-sm-4 text-right norightpadding">First Name</label>
    <div class="input-group" [ngClass]="{'errmsg': !form.controls['lastname'].valid, 'errmsg' : !form.controls['lastname'].pristine }">
        <input type="text" [formControl]="form.controls['lastname']">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <button type="submit">Register now</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Form validation classes work on the below cases

- ng-valid - Boolean Tells whether an item is currently valid based on the rules you placed.
- ng-invalid - Boolean Tells whether an item is currently invalid based on the rules you placed.
- ng-pristine - Boolean True if the form/input has not been used yet.
- ng-dirty  - Boolean True if the form/input has been used.
- ng-touched - Boolean True if the input has been blurred.

For more info refer here

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation

Comment: Thank you,i want to show validation when button is clicked

Comment: [ngClass]="{errmsg: !form.controls['lastname'].valid && || (!form.controls['lastname'].pristine && form.submitted)...........will it wrk

Comment: No this is not the right method i think, error message should be shown at the time of filling text into textfield not at the time of button click

Comment: if you really want to do the same thing then trigger one variable on button click and on the basis of trigger you can show all the validation once, but this is not the preferable method ever.