# How to use directives in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to load my navbar.html in my app.component.html for that i used directives and follwed the below method,

my navbar html,

```
<p>Hi i am a pen</p>
```

my navbar.ts,

```
 import {Component,Directive, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
    selector: 'header-Navbar',
    templateUrl: './app/navbar/navbar.html',
     })
    export class Navbar  {}
```

my app.component.html,

```
    <header-Navbar></header-Navbar>
```

my app.component.ts,

```
import {Component,Directive, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Navbar }  from '../navbar/navbar';
import {PathLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy, Location} from '@angular/common';
import { Config } from '../headers';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives : [Navbar],---->Saying type error
    templateUrl: './app/components/app.component.html',
    providers: [Config]
})
```

My error,

```
   'header-Navbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'header-Navbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'header-Navbar' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
        [ERROR ->]<header-Navbar></header-Navbar>
```

This is my situation and i am not sure about how to solve it,can any one suggest me help.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`directives` in `@Component()` is gone since a while.

Now they should be in

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [NavBar]
  ...
}
export class AppModule {} 
// or 
export class MyOtherModule {}
```

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html

Comment: Gunter,can you see this......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146587/how-to-show-validation-on-button-click-in-typescript

Answer (score 3):

Your app.component

```
@Component({ // <--- removed directives
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app/components/app.component.html',
    providers: [Config]
})
```

Your app.module

```
import { Navbar }  from '../navbar/navbar';
@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    exports: [],
    declarations: [Navbar], // <-- imported here
    providers: [],
})
```